# Error: Could not add AttachedObjectHandler to MyFaces, after migration to Websphere Liberty 8.5.5?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, websphere, websphere-liberty

Trying to migrate my project from Websphere 8.0 to Websphere Liberty Profile 8.5.5 and get the following error (actually it's printed multiple time):

```
[ERROR   ] Could not add AttachedObjectHandler to MyFaces!
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletCompositionContext
```

At the same time it seems that functionality has not been affected. When it run at Websphere 8.0 I don't see this error.

My features list of Websphere Liberty is following:

```
    <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
    <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    <feature>cdi-1.2</feature>
    <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
    <feature>jsf-2.2</feature>
```

Thank you

**UPDATE**: Ok, it's known issue: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7998  **now I'm looking for advice how to solve this issue**

Comment: Try to post on [dwAnswers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/24/wasdev.html) or create a PMR in the IBM support.

Comment: The WAS team do look at questions here, so there is no need to double post to dwAnswers.

Comment: I raised an issue on primefaces based on the comments in 7998 https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/680